# How to create a search text field in kivymd?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

How can I implement a dynamic auto-suggestion feature for three text fields (Father's name, Mother's name, Child's name) in a form? When a user focuses on a specific text field and inputs a name (e.g., 'Raj'), I want to perform a database search for matching names and present them in a dropdown menu. The user can then select a name from the dropdown menu, and the chosen name should be populated back into the same text field.

This is my relationship.py file

```
class Family_Tree(MDApp):
    db_engine = DB()
    add_person_selection = None

    def build(self):
        Window.size = (360, 640)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_file("add_relationship.kv")

    def error_max_field_length(self, instance, limit):
        temp_prior = instance.text
        temp_prior_splits = list(temp_prior)
        if len(temp_prior_splits) > limit:
            temp_prior_splits.pop(-1)
            instance.text = ''.join(temp_prior_splits)

    def handle_textfield_focus(self, text_field, focus):
        if focus:
            self.show_dropdown_menu(text_field)
        else:
            self.dismiss_dropdown_menu()

    def show_dropdown_menu(self, text_field):
        menu_items = [
            {"text": f"Item {i}", "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.set_item(x)}
            for i in range(1, 6)
        ]

        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=text_field,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=8,
        )

        self.menu.open()

    def dismiss_dropdown_menu(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'menu') and self.menu:
            self.menu.dismiss()

    def set_item(self, text):
        self.root.ids.text_field.text = text
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def submit_action(self):
        selected_item = self.root.ids.text_field.text
        print(f"Selected item: {selected_item}")

Family_Tree().run()
```

and here is my add_relationship.kv file

```
MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: self.theme_cls.backgroundColor

    MDBoxLayout:
        id: add_person_box_layout
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        y: root.height - self.height - dp(10)
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 50
        padding: 10

        MDLabel:
            text: "Add Relationship Details"
            font_style: "Title"

        MDTextField:
            id: father_name
            mode: "filled"
            multiline : False
            on_text: app.error_max_field_length(father_name, 20)
            on_focus: app.handle_textfield_focus(self, self.focus)

            MDTextFieldHintText:
                text: "Father Name"

        MDTextField:
            id: mother_name
            mode: "filled"
            multiline : False
            on_text: app.error_max_field_length(father_name, 20)
            on_focus: app.handle_textfield_focus(self, self.focus)

            MDTextFieldHintText:
                text: "Mother Name"

        MDTextField:
            id: child_name
            mode: "filled"
            multiline : False
            on_text: app.error_max_field_length(child_name, 20)

            MDTextFieldHintText:
                text: "Child Name"


        MDButton:
            style: "filled"
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : .5}
            on_press: app.add_person_submit()

            MDButtonText:
                text: "Submit"
```

Also im using the Kivymd 2.0 version